# In Thor: The Dark World, what is the name of the language that Malekith and the other svartalfr speak?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, languages, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

I find answers acceptable in the following order:

1. Name from the script of *Thor: The Dark World*.
2. Name specific to this language in Marvel comic books that make mention of the dark elves.
3. The correct name as it would be in Norse mythology (some variation of svartal- that I don't know enough to figure out).

Very good answers might provide all 3 versions.

I've only been able to find articles with Eccleston complaining about how tedious it was to learn it for the movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer does not quite fit the three categories you have provided, but is direct from the creator of the language.  The language is called Shiväisith ([translates to "The Soft Speech" in Shiväisith](http://dedalvs.tumblr.com/post/67483676828/mr-peterson-you-are-awesome-i-just-saw-thor-2-for)) and it was created specifically for the Thor 2 movie by David J. Peterson (He also created the Dothraki & Valayrian languages and dialects used in the TV adaption of Game of Thrones based off partial language fragments in the books).  Shiväisith is a working language, even if it's vocab is limited and very specific to the movie, with working grammar rules etc.  More can be found on [David Peterson's Shiväisith Tumblr](http://dedalvs.tumblr.com/tagged/Shiv%C3%A4isith) entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but given that the Old Norse word for language is "mál", the proper name for this language according to Norse mythology would probably be:

*Svartálfamál*

This doesn't take into account discrepancies from the Marvel movie mythology and Norse mythology, since they clearly refer to Thor and his people as "Asgardians" rather than the proper name of "Aesir". But a week of off and on Google searches have not turned up a proper Marvel name for this language. Absent any clearly-attested names, defaulting to the Old Norse name makes sense.